# Postgres with elasticsearch (keep in sync) - nodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, elasticsearch, redis, synchronization

I want to set up postgres and elasticsearch. But before throwing data into elasticsearch, I want to prevent data loss when network or server goes down. After reading on this topic: https://gocardless.com/blog/syncing-postgres-to-elasticsearch-lessons-learned/. I came up with 3 solutions.

1. Create a database table ei: `store`, and add any new/updated data to it.

   - During queries: insert data into `store`.
   - Select new data: `SELECT data FROM store WHERE modified > (:last modified time from elasticsearch)`
   - Send "new" data over to elasticsearch
2. Use redis to `pub/sub` requests, and make elasticsearch listen/subscribe for upcoming data. If elasticsearch breaks, the data will be in the queue
3. Catch any errors during transaction to elasticsearch and save data into a safe place (ei: `store` table mentioned above). Then have a cron job pushing this data back.

---

Of course the easiest thing would be to insert data to elasticsearch straight away. But doing so prevents data to be stored in a safe place during corruptions. `1` is too slow in my opinion, unlike `2`. And `3` requires mantaining error handling code.

For now `2` is my option.

---

Are there better ways to do this? I'd like to hear your opinions and **new** suggestions

:D

Comment: Just curious, how would handle DELETES for case 1.  I was just exploring options to do exactly what you are doing...

Comment: Also, check this out... https://qafoo.com/blog/086_how_to_synchronize_a_database_with_elastic_search.html

Comment: @FacePalm  see anwser

Comment: heres my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757377/sync-elasticsearch-on-connection-with-database-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Redis (2) isn't reliable.

What I decided to do add data to elasticsearch straight away and add data to `updates` table. Then run a `sync()` function straight after connecting to elasticsearch client (if cluster went down before) + run a cron job every 24 hours to launch `sync()`. All `sync()` does is selects newest data (time or id) from `updates` **A** and elasticsearch **B**  and compares if there are records `A > B`. If so, insert data using bulk API.

Hope this helps :)

And I am still opened to suggestions and fedback...